# How to easily compare a domain object with related entities in order to update database with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

For my ASP.NET Core API project, I am smoothly moving from a standard repository pattern approach (with most of the business logic in the repo layer) to the very seducing DDD approach. My domain object are and will always be different from my entities as I am maintaining an existing application with a db in place.

So the process would be (correct me if I am mistaken):

1. load the aggregate from the database
2. do the work in the app layer (relying of course on the domain model / inner logic) and
3. update the database with the result

Step (1) is ok thanks to automapper.

Step (2) is great, (OO programming, finally !)

Step (3) is my problem: I still hold the initial entity model from step (1) and I have a domain model from step (2) that I can revert into entities thanks to Automapper again.

Question: is there a method way to compare entities (1) and (2) and ask EF Core 2.1 to do the update (using states maybe)?

I am already using `AddOrUpdate()` which is fine for Add Or Update indeed, but not for removing value objects for instance.

Comment: Take a look at Vaughn Vernon’s article https://kalele.io/blog-posts/modeling-aggregates-with-ddd-and-entity-framework/ . I prefer second approach described, object backed by state objects.

Comment: If someone is interested in the answer : I ended up using ObjectState as per Julie Lerman advice https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt767693.aspx